$L^1$ convergence
Setting

For $i \in \mathbb{N}$, consider two sequences $f_i,g_i \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$ f_i \rightarrow_{L^1} f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) $$ and also $$ g_i \rightarrow_{L^1} g \in L^1(\mathbb{R}).$$

Assume that all the functions involved are (1) striclty positive and that for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we have (2) $$ 0 < \int_\mathbb{R} f_i^2 g_i^{-1} < \infty$$ and also (3) $$  0 < \int_\mathbb{R} f^2 g^{-1} < \infty $$


Question
Do we have the following convergence $$\int_\mathbb{R} f_i^2 g_i^{-1} \rightarrow \int_\mathbb{R} f^2 g^{-1} $$

If you look at $$ \int f_i^{\frac{1}{2}}g^{\frac{1}{2}}_i $$ instead then you do have convergence... But you need to use Holder whereas in this setting $(2,-1)$ you cannot (the natural scaling that pops up is Reverse holder...)

No, this is not true. The following argument is about spaces of finite measure, but it can easily be adapted to your question about $\mathbb R$.
Let $(X, m)$ be a space with $m(X) < \infty$. Take $g_i = g = 1$, and $f=0$. You are then asking the following:

if $f_i \in L^2 (X) \subseteq L^1 (X)$, and if $f_i \to 0$ in $L^1 (X)$, does it follow that $f_i \to 0$ in $L^2 (X)$?

No, it does not: take $X = [0,1] \subset \mathbb R$, and $f_i = i \; 1_{[0, \frac 1 {i^2}]}$ (with $1_A$ the indicator function of the subset $A$). Then
$f_i \to 0$ in $L^1$ but $\| f_i \| _{L^2} = 1 \not\to 0$ in $L^2$.

Thank you ! But I think your counter example does not work because $f$ is not strictly positive as assume in the statement...

@Anthony shift $f_i$ to $f_i + c$ for a positive constant $c$

@Anthony: As Hannes says, take for instance $f_i = 1 + i ; 1_{[0, \frac 1 {i^2}]}$ and $f=1$.

Yeah you right sry..
